# Pourquoi dit-on « à vos/tes souhaits ! » quand quelqu'un a éternué ?

Tags: expressions, usage, origine-ou-raison

Dans ma langue maternelle, c'est à dire l'espagnol, on dit « salud! » (santé!) à quelqu'un qui vient tout juste d'éternuer, avec l'intention de lui souhaiter précisément de la santé.

Cependant, en français, on dit plutôt « à vos/tes souhaits! ». Quelle est la raison pour laquelle on dit ça? quelle est la logique derrière cette réponse? et en tout cas, à quels souhaits on se réfère?

J'ai trouvé [l'explication](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/souhaits) suivante mais je ne suis pas très convaincu.

Answer (score 3):

Il existe une [très](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_tes_souhaits) [grande](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/souhaits) [quantité](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/a-vos-souhaits.php) d'[explications](http://www.jesuiscultive.com/spip.php?article511), [toutes](http://www.linternaute.com/expression/langue-francaise/5503/a-vos-souhaits/) plus ou moins en [relation](http://fr.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20061007011542AA2ZB5v) avec [diverses](http://www.lexpress.to/archives/5931/) [croyances](http://www.castalie.fr/article-473476.html).

Mais je ne sais pas si l'une d'elle est vraie...

Comment: (+1) merci pour la collection ! Amusant de voir comme chaque hypothèse est toujours un peu trop péremptoire...