# How do I say "Bless" in French when someone sneezes?

Tags: vocabulaire

How do I say "Bless" in French when someone sneezes?
I Portuguese, it's Saúde. In English, Blesses [God bless you!]
What about French?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to say in ceremonies, incidents and some situations in French ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30219/what-to-say-in-ceremonies-incidents-and-some-situations-in-french) - See also : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6368/pourquoi-dit-on-à-vos-tes-souhaits-quand-quelquun-a-éternué

Comment: It is not "bless" in English. It's: **Bless you**.

Comment: This is something that can be looked up in a dictionary. See, for example, [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/bless-you) and [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-french/bless?q=bless+you).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick googling of "bless you sneeze in french" reveals very easily the desired answer.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Response_to_sneezing

[image]

http://franconaija.blogspot.com/2015/05/what-to-say-in-french-when-someone.html

https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/god-bless-you-bless-you-sneezing.2058/

From the last link

> 1st sneeze : A tes/vos souhaits!
>
> 2nd sneeze : A tes/vos amours! (que
> les tiennes/vôtres durent toujours)
>
> 3rd sneeze : A tes/vos aïeux!
>
> 4th
> sneeze : Crève!

https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-say-bless-you-in-French-when-someone-sneezes

Comment: Upvote because I happened to learn something new (not that this is very exceptional, but still) with the 2nd, 3rd and 4th sneezes.

Comment: @LaurentS. Je te remercie:-)!

Answer (score 3):

In French, we say "À tes souhaits" ou "À vos souhaits"

[Dictionary link here](https://www.wordreference.com/enfr/Bless%20you!)